# Is it possible to make a telegram bot for individual messages

Tags: python

Is it possible to make a telegram bot for individual messages:

1. There is a channel in which there are 100 people and a bot has been added.
2. the bot is able to answer a question on request.
   Task: Is it possible to make sure that the questions to the bot and the answers to the bot are seen only by the person who accesses the bot and not everything in the channel.

I tried to add the bot to the group, but all users see access to it